# Reverse photosensor is activating an LED but won’t activate a motor

Tags: led, motor, photosensor

I am trying to use a photosensor in reverse so that it activates when it is dark instead of light.

I am using a 2N222 transistor. I tested with an LED and it works fine, but when I use the same circuit for a motor it does not work.

It has 3V across the LED and 8.1V across the diode when just using a diode in its place. I tried putting the diode and LED in line and it doesn’t turn on the LED. I tried removing the diodes altogether, still no voltage. I also tried removing the 100 ohm resistor, then the 100k resistor and nothing. I tried reversing the diodes and nothing. Any ideas on why the motor won’t turn on? I think I might be misunderstanding how the transistor works.

I also tried switching the position of the diode and the motor

I also tried making a parallel circuit with the diode and the motor, the rest the same.

This is my schematic

[image]

Comment: Most motors need a lot more current to operate than an LED does. Which motor are you trying to use?

Comment: It’s 12V. I figured if 8.1V passed through the diode, it should’ve worked?

Comment: Have you tried adding the motor in parallel with the LED+resistor instead of in series? The motor is not turning because of the 100 ohms resistor preventing the motor from pulling enough power to make it turn

Comment: `use a photosensor in reverse` ... there is no "reverse" ... the sensor response to light does not change

Comment: _"It’s 12V."_ - this means very little. Can you tell us anything else about it?

Comment: @jsotola it works for the led, but not the motor

Comment: @BruceAbbott I’m not home but it’s very similar to this. I’ll get exact model later https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00NN2YUWQ/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_glt_fabc_8GK6GATGQEG4E1E8MN2B?pldnSite=1

Comment: @thisjt I will try this later! I think I might have tried it but realized the transistor went bad after so thought it didn’t work…. May have been from flipping things ways they shouldn’t be

Comment: @SamanthaCruz:  Does the motor run when connected straight to the battery?

Comment: @JRE yes it does

Comment: @SamanthaCruz your transistors might be going bad because of back-emf killing it when the motor stops. You should add a flyback diode (look it up, there's a lot of things you need to know about it) in parallel to your motor to mitigate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In darkness, you will have a bit less than 90 uA base current.

Multiply that by the current gain (beta, Hfe) of your transistor, and compare that with the stall current (= starting current) of your motor.

Example :
Hfe = 100 * 90 uA = 9 mA (plenty for an LED by the way)
Motor rated at 1A : starting current typically about 5A.

Can you see a problem?

> I think not enough amperage?

Exactly. Not enough current.

When it's sufficiently dark, the LDR is a high resistance, so the 100K supplies a small base current, and that limits the collector current. If you reduce that resistor you'll get more current, but you'll also change the threshold of darkness required.

Now look up "Darlington transistor" (which you can make from two of your existing transistors). With 100x more current gain, you'd get 900mA which would drive a small motor, but not a big one. (For a bigger motor, you'd need a power transistor, and maybe 2 small transistors driving it)

[image: schematic]

Looking at that motor, you may find transistor Q2 gets hot, and either needs a heatsink, or a power transistor, or both. And there are better approaches than this simple driver, but this is good for an experiment. (Really, you want to snap the transistor switch fully on or fully off; at the wrong brightness this will be halfway on and waste a lot of power. But doing that is a separate question)

Comment: I think not enough amperage? I am totally lost on how the transistor works honestly. I get how it used positively and negatively charged electrons to control current flow, but I’m at a loss on how the resistors make it change the resistance of the LDR from being higher in light rather than dark

Comment: Does the current stop at the motor because the amp rating is too low?

Comment: Current that can drive a LED simply won't be enough to start any normal motor (so you need to lose that 100R for the motor)

Comment: Ok I will try when I get home

Comment: The current doesn't stop; current still flows through the motor, it's just not enough current to make it spin.

Comment: So then the second transistor acts as an amplifier since the 100k resistor reduces the current, and therefore it does not have enough amperage without it

Comment: Do I need a diode?

Comment: What would you do with a diode here?

Comment: Note you need more than just the motors operating current.   A motor is basically a short-circuit at startup, expect a surge 3-5x the normal.  If your circuit can't provide that much current, the motor won't start spinning.   Switching your transistor to a logic-level MOSFET may help immensely as those are 'voltage controlled' not 'current controlled'.  Your photodiode only need create enough voltage to turn the MOSFET gate on.

Comment: This worked and thanks for helping me understand how the transistors work!

Comment: So now on to better approaches… using an IR LED diode pair?